# WMP in c# play rate

Tags: wmp

I am using wmp in my windows application. I want to change the rate of the play speed.
It is possible for some type of files e.g; avi. But its not possible for some types, eg; wmv,mpeg etc. Is there any other way to change rate. Please, its urgent. Thanx in advance

Answer (score 0):

Its possible, but your choice of using windows media player will limit your choices. Windows media player uses a very simple graphfilter to control playback. This will make it impossible to change the rate for formats which require more complex filters. The general way to change the rate is to either repeat or drop frames in the video.

I am not sure about wmv, but if memory serves me right, wmv is just a container format like AVI, so the graphfilter that is used varies from file to file.

mpeg has 3 kinds of frames. only the i frame is complete. the p and b frames are not so you cant really repeat or drop the frames easily.

Dont know how to help you with this, but you will have better choices if your using directshow so that you can change graphfilters to duplicate/drop frames.

Comment: Thank you Andrew, I have tried Directshow. Its possible with directshow, but there is very bad sound quality in slow motion. So if is it possible to convert wmv to avi or another programatically i will try this. I am using c#.